# Name comparison in java.lang.reflect.Method.equals(Object obj)

Tags: java, reflection

Here's the implementation of `java.lang.reflect.Method.equals(Object obj)` as of Java 7:

```
/**
 * Compares this {@code Method} against the specified object.  Returns
 * true if the objects are the same.  Two {@code Methods} are the same if
 * they were declared by the same class and have the same name
 * and formal parameter types and return type.
 */
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null && obj instanceof Method) {
        Method other = (Method)obj;
        if ((getDeclaringClass() == other.getDeclaringClass())
            && (getName() == other.getName())) {
            if (!returnType.equals(other.getReturnType()))
                return false;
            /* Avoid unnecessary cloning */
            Class<?>[] params1 = parameterTypes;
            Class<?>[] params2 = other.parameterTypes;
            if (params1.length == params2.length) {
                for (int i = 0; i < params1.length; i++) {
                    if (params1[i] != params2[i])
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The most interesting part here is comparison of method names: `getName() == other.getName()`. Those return `java.lang.String` and hence a natural question is whether it's valid to compare them by references (`==`). While this code obviously works the question is whether it can be a source of bugs in reflection-oriented frameworks. What do you think?

Comment: Maybe the one who wrote `getName() == other.getName()` wants to check whether the two `name` references refer to the same object in the memory or not, rather than checking the actual string values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing interesting when you look directly on name attribute of Method class.

```
 // This is guaranteed to be interned by the VM in the 1.4
// reflection implementation
private String              name;
```

So by interning String you can directly compare reference.

More on [String.intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29)

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not true for all Java VMs. I.e. the Dalvik VM on Android does not return interned Strings from Method.getName or at least not always.